# Making \multlined behave like \multline

Tags: equations, align, multline

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
a = b = c = d  = e\\
= f = g = h = i = j
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\begin{multline}
a = b = c = d = e\\
= f = g = h = i = j
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

When using `multlined`, the equation is completely centred on both lines, whereas when using `multline`, the first line is flushed left while all subsequent lines are flushed right. I prefer the latter.

On the other hand, I tend to use the `multlined` environment, as it centres the equation labels nicely.

So: Is there any way of changing the alignment of the `multlined` environment to something like that of the `multline` environment?

Many thanks.

Comment: multilined flushes the first line left and the second right in the same way but in a text block that fits the width of the lines. multiline does the same but in a block that fits the width of the page.  (same with aligned v align and gathered v gather)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason for having the equation number at the bottom, with `multline`: that's where the equation ends.

You can tell `multlined` to get wider (the measurement could be more precise). But why?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathtoolsset{multlined-width=0.9\displaywidth}
\begin{multlined}
a = b = c = d  = e\\
= f = g = h = i = j
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\begin{multline}
a = b = c = d = e\\
= f = g = h = i = j
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]